# Linker error with boost serialization: missing lib file

Tags: c++, boost-serialization, vc10

I have VC 10 and using boost 1.53.0.
I am trying to compile and link a sample program from boost serialization [samples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp%22), but the linker generates the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib".
```

I tried many things, like checking my include and lib paths, all was correct. In fact this file name which the linker was asking is not there even in the whole c drive where both MS VC 10 and boost are installed.

Thank you.

Comment: Does `libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib` exist? Or probably `boost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib`?

Comment: No it does not exist on my computer. Infact I have tried locating it on the web but zero results.

Comment: Read this -http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries. Means you have to build this lib or to find it on the web.

Comment: I also did a search for boost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib but nothing came up. however earlier versions of this file are available such as libboost_serialization-vc80-mt-gd-1_43.lib.

Comment: Latest versions of almost everything (GCC, Boost, etc) are to be built by yourself.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I built the boost and got the library, its working great.